# Code not evaluated in default argument value specification

Tags: ruby, local-variables, lexical-scope

(At least some kind of) Ruby code is accepted and evaluated within the default value specification of a method. In below, `"foo" * 3` is evaluated:

```
def bar baz = "foo" * 3; baz end
bar # => "foofoofoo"

def bar baz: "foo" * 3; baz end
bar # => "foofoofoo"
```

However, when I try to evaluate a local variable/method under a certain scope in the default value description as follows, the local variable/method is evaluated under lexical scope:

```
MAIN = TOPLEVEL_BINDING.eval('self')
foo = 3

def bar baz = MAIN.instance_eval{foo}; end
bar # => undefined local variable or method `foo' for main:Object

def bar baz: MAIN.instance_eval{foo}; end
bar # => undefined local variable or method `foo' for main:Object
```

- Why is `foo` above not evaluated within `MAIN` scope and is evaluated in lexical scope?
- This seems there is some limitation to what Ruby expressions can be evaluated in the default value description. What exactly can be put there?

Answer (score 1):

`foo` is local variable for `main`. Your attempt to access local variable from outside might be shorten to:

```
▶ MAIN = TOPLEVEL_BINDING.eval('self')
▶ foo = 3
▶ MAIN.foo
#⇒ NoMethodError: undefined method `foo' for main:Object
```

The analogue of this code in less tangled manner is:

```
class A
  foo = 5
end

class B
  def a_foo
    A.new.foo
  end
end

▶ B.new.a_foo
#⇒ NoMethodError: undefined method `foo' for #<A:0x00000002293bd0>
```

If you want to provide access from the universe to your local variable you are to implement *getter*:

```
def MAIN.foo ; 5 ; end
def bar baz = MAIN.instance_eval{foo}; baz; end

▶ bar
#⇒ 5
```

Hope it helps.